# Explit conformance to Codable removes memberwise initializer generation on structs

Tags: swift, codable

Given:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: Bar
}
```

I get a convenience initializer to use:

`let foo = Foo(bar: Bar())`

But if `Bar` isn't itself `Codable`, or for some other reason I need to explicitly implement `Codable` on `Foo` then the convenience memberwise initializer is no longer present:

```
struct Foo: Codable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

    }

    let bar: Bar
}
```

and i get:

`let foo = Foo(bar: Bar())`

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'bar:', expected 'from:')

---

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can implement the `Codable` conformance in an extension.

When adding any struct initializer in an extension, the memberwise initializer will not be removed.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var name: String
}
extension MyStruct: Codable {} // preserves memberwise initializer

MyStruct(name: "Tim")
```

Comment: I love this, it's a pretty nice way to distinguish the "replace" vs "extend" semantics. You want to extend what's already there? Use an extension! :D

Comment: What?! come on, Apple. You can do better than that. fgs... -_-

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work if struct is inside a framework.

Comment: Super awesome answer, I was banging my head over this issue and this just saved me