# SwiftUI: How to display multiple pins on Map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, swiftui, geolocation, location

So I currently have this code that displays a map with a pin in it.

But I was wondering how I Can display multiple pins and not just one and also display the users current location, so if the user moves the "dot" should also move

And if the users clicks on of the pins I would like to print something to the console

```
  struct GeoPointView : View {
        var position : GeoPoint
        
        struct IdentifiablePoint: Identifiable {
            var id = UUID()
            var position : GeoPoint
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(
                    MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))), annotationItems: [position].map { IdentifiablePoint(position: $0)}) { point in
                
                MapPin(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point.position.latitude, longitude: point.position.longitude))
            }
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To display multiple points, you'll want an array of `GeoPoint`s.

Then, you'd probably want to do some rationalization of where the map is centered/zoomed to see all of the points. I've included this in my `centerOfPoints` calculated property.

```
struct GeoPointView : View {
    var positions : [GeoPoint]
    
    struct IdentifiablePoint: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var position : GeoPoint
    }
    
    var centerOfPoints : (center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, span: MKCoordinateSpan) {
        var minLat = 91.0
        var maxLat = -91.0
        var minLon = 181.0
        var maxLon = -181.0
        
        for i in positions {
            maxLat = max(maxLat, i.latitude)
            minLat = min(minLat, i.latitude)
            maxLon = max(maxLon, i.longitude)
            minLon = min(minLon, i.longitude)
        }
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (maxLat + minLat) / 2,
                                           longitude: (maxLon + minLon) / 2)
        
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: abs(maxLat - minLat) * 1.3,
                                    longitudeDelta: abs(maxLon - minLon) * 1.3)
        return (center: center,
                span: span)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let center = centerOfPoints
        
        return Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(MKCoordinateRegion(center: center.center, span: center.span)), showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: positions.map { IdentifiablePoint(position: $0)}) { (point) in
            MapPin(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point.position.latitude,
                                                      longitude: point.position.longitude))
        }
    }
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
GeoPointView(positions: [GeoPoint(latitude: 43.0, longitude: -75),
                                 GeoPoint(latitude: 41.0, longitude: -75),
                                 GeoPoint(latitude: 41.0, longitude: -85),
        ])
```

I've added a `showsUserLocation: true` to the map to show the blue dot for user location. Note that this requires additional setup, adding to your Info.plist and requesting permission to access location data. https://fluffy.es/current-location/ seems like a reasonable tutorial for some of this. If you need additional help getting the permissions set up, I'd suggest splitting that off into another question as this one is already quite large in scope.

I'm not seeing an API available for telling if a map pin has been tapped, although perhaps someone else will chime in with info about that.

Comment: I haven't tried the code yet because I ran into some major issues with my project. But I will let you know as soon as I get back to my project and try out the code